# On Réalis’s solution of the “cubic Markov equation”

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, cubics

I am interested in the Diophantine equation
$$X^3+Y^3+Z^3=3XYZ$$
and its solutions. In [Nouv. Corr. Math. 1879 (page 7)](https://books.google.ca/books?id=UlFOAAAAYAAJ), Réalis claims that, other than the trivial solution $x=y=z$, the complete solution in integers is given by
$$
x=(a-b)^3+(a-c)^3, \quad y=(b-c)^3+(b-a)^3, \quad z=(c-a)^3+(c-b)^3.
$$
It’s easy to show that these values suffice — by simply substituting and doing the algebra — but the result seems just a little too convenient for my tastes…

Does anyone know how to prove [or disprove] the claim? Are there any known solutions that don’t fit Réalis’s parameterization?

Comment: because $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 - 3xyz = (x+y+z)(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - yz -zx-xy)$

Comment: @Will Jagy: No, I typed it correctly — see the link I provided (page 7 of that book).

Comment: I've edited my question to try to make it clearer.

Comment: Kieren, something is off, then. The $x,y,z$   supplied do satisfy $x+y+z = 0$  and that is all that is needed.  Take any number $z$  that is NOT the sum or difference of two cubes, take any $y,$  then $x = -y-z.$

Comment: So strange. In Dickson's History, volume 2, page 590, he reports on Realis, same as you say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite wrong. We have

$$x^3 + y^3 + z^3 - 3xyz = (x + y + z)(x + y \omega + z \omega^2)(x + y \omega^2 + z \omega)$$

where $\omega = e^{ \frac{2 \pi i}{3} }$ is a primitive third root of unity. This identity comes from recognizing the LHS as the determinant of the [circulant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix) $\left[ \begin{array}{ccc} x & y & z \\ z & x & y \\ y & z & x \end{array} \right]$ and using a standard fact about the eigenvalues of circulant matrices. Setting this product equal to zero, we need to solve

$$x + y + z = 0 \text{ or } x + y \omega + z \omega^2 = 0 \text{ or } x + y \omega^2 + z \omega = 0.$$

The first equation is very easy and we get a parameterized family of solutions $\boxed{ x = t, y = s, z = - t - s }$, which amounts to the identity

$$t^3 + s^3 - (t + s)^3 = - 3 ts(t + s)$$

which is not hard to check. The given parametric solution only allows values of $x, y, z$ which are a sum of two cubes so it doesn't include all of these solutions.

For the second two equations, we have $1 + \omega + \omega^2 = 0$ so $\omega^2 = -1 - \omega$. This means the first equation is equivalent to

$$x + y \omega - z(1 + \omega) = (x - z) + (y - z) \omega = 0$$

so $\boxed{ x = y = z }$, and the second equation also gives this. We can also argue without using complex numbers by instead writing

$$\begin{eqnarray*} (x + y \omega + z \omega^2)(x + y \omega^2 + z \omega) &=& x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - xy - yz - zx \\
 &=& \frac{(x - y)^2 + (y - z)^2 + (z - x)^2}{2} \end{eqnarray*}$$

which is clearly $\ge 0$ with equality case $x = y = z$.

Comment: Qiaochu, this is in Dickson's History, volume 2, pages 590-591.   At this point, I wish I could read French...in 17.Remarque he seems well aware that $x+y+z=0$   solves the given problem

Comment: Yeah, it seemed too good to be true. I think Réalis was just wrong, and Dickson didn’t explicitly say so.

Comment: Maybe Réalis meant that his parameterization is _a_ set of solutions, since $x+y+z=0$?

Comment: Seulement un peu…

Comment: oh, well. Cubes are $0, \pm 1 \pmod 9$   and $0,\pm 1 \pmod 7.$  So $3$ is not a sum of two cubes.  $3^3 + (-2)^3 + (-1)^3 =  18, \; \; \; \;$   $ 3 \cdot 3 \cdot (-2) \cdot (-1) = 18 $